# Matlab double() returning 0 for sym

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Here is the code that is giving me trouble.

```matlab
>> x_flex

x_flex =

sigma == 140512308373959475200/8004146304532579

>> double(x_flex)

ans =

     0
```

Where `x_flex` is a `1x1 sym`.

What I want is for matlab to do the division and return a number in this case: `1.7555e+04`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solving `x_flex` for `sigma` seems to do make it work:

```matlab
x_flex =

sigma == 140512308373959475200/8004146304532579

>> solve(x_flex)

ans =

140512308373959475200/8004146304532579

>> double(ans)

ans =

   1.7555e+04
```

Comment: This was because `x_flex` was a symbolic equation, not a variable.